# Evaluate $\int \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\,\operatorname d\!x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I`m trying to solve this integral and I did the following steps to solve it but don't know how to continue.
$$\int \dfrac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\,\operatorname d\!x$$

$$\begin{align}\int \dfrac{\operatorname d\!x}{\sin^2(x)}+\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\,\operatorname d\!x &= \int \dfrac{\operatorname d\!x}{\sin^2(x)}+\int \frac{\cos(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)} \\
&=\int \sin^{-2}(x)\,\operatorname d\!x + \int \cos(x)\,\operatorname d\!x - \int \frac{\operatorname d\!x}{\cos(x)}\end{align}$$
Any suggestions how to continue?

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid writing $\dfrac{1}{\sin^2 x}$ as $\sin ^{-2} x$.

Comment: err... $\frac1{a-b} \ne \frac1a - \frac1b$.

Comment: Ah, didnt see that, realy bad.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}dx=\int \frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)}+\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}dx$$

$$=\int \csc^2xdx+\int\csc x\cot xdx=-\cot x-\csc x+C$$

---

Alternatively, $$\int \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}dx=\int \frac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}dx=\int \frac{dx}{1-\cos x}$$

$$\text{Use }\cos x=\frac {1-\tan^2\frac x2}{1+\tan^2\frac x2}$$ and put $\tan\frac x2=u$ ([Weierstrass substitution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html) formulas)

Comment: do you have maybe another way ? because I dont use $csc$. thanks

Comment: @OfirAttia, find the alternative method

Comment: thanks I see that, you use there in universal integration?

Comment: @OfirAttia, what is universal integration?

Comment: Maybe that how its called here or I dont know, but as you say if $tan(\frac{x}{2}) = u$ so $$cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ $$sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ $$\tan(x)=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$$ $$x=2arctan(t)$$ $$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$

Comment: In other words it is related to the Weierstrass Substitution as I see now

Comment: @OfirAttia, yes.I know it by Weierstrass Substitution

Comment: After a few algebraic steps I get $\int \frac{1+t^2}{2t^2}dt$ its still complicate, or I should put $dx$ as $\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$ here?

Comment: OK so if I put $dx$ as $\frac{2}{1+t^2}$ so I get $$\int \frac{1+t^2 \frac{2}{1+t^2}}{2t^2}$$ so its OK.

Comment: You don't use $\csc$???

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

$1+\cos x=2 \cos^2 \dfrac{x}{2}$

$\sin^2 x=(2\sin\dfrac{x}{2} \cos \dfrac{x}{2})^2$

You expression will be $\dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{1}{\sin^2\dfrac{x}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\int\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx=\int\frac1{\sin^2x}dx+\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;(\cot x)'=-\frac1{\sin^2x}$$

$$(3)\;\;\;\text{for a derivable function}\;f : \int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^m}dx=\frac{f(x)^{1-m}}{1-m}+C\;,\;\;\color{blue}{m\neq -1}$$